# Restore files from vmdk with logical volumes

Tags: lvm, vmware

I need to restore some files from some vmdk that were mounted on a VM with some logical volumes.

Is it possible to use a new VM booted from a CentOS iso and mount these vmdk in order to obtain the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible in the following steps:

- add/attach your *vmdk* file as new Hard Drive (chose *Use an existing virtual disk*) to your CentOS VM.
- load CentOS VM.
- type `pvs -ay` to scan your physical LVM devices: the `-ay` option activates it.
- type `vgchange -ay` to activate all LVM groups and volumes on it.
- type `lvs` to show LVM volumes and therefore mount them by absolute path (`/dev/<volume_group>/<volume_name>`).

Comment: an edit *and an upvote!*  **:-)**

Comment: @Fabby Thank's! ;) I've made simply grammar mistakes. I'ill be more carefully in the future.

Comment: Нет проблем. Я делаю кучу ошибок на русском языке...

Comment: Hi @Yurij Goncharuk. I have an error during the activation of the vgroup: Refusing activation of partial LV lv_root. Use --activationmode partial to override. What can I do?

Comment: Hi @intore, please append to your question output of these commands: `lsblk`, `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs`.

Comment: I'm working from a vmware console and I can't copy/paste text. I just used the --activationmode option but some I can't see the full content of some lv

Comment: @intore can you start open-ssh server from VMware console and connect to VM from your host system?

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk: unfortunatelly I can't. I just activated the vg but I can't mount the one I need. The message is "mount failed. Bad message"

Comment: Hi @YurijGoncharuk. I solved with this document: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/400173 and with your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @intore You are welcome!